# Django simple form "object has no attribute 'is_hidden'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm trying to render a simple form with no db models but I am getting error. Following is the code:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    category_options = (
        ('select category', '--Select Category--'),
        ('fire safety', 'Fire Safety'),
        ('batteries/solar panels', 'Batteries/Solar Panels'),
        ( 'cctv systems','CCTV Systems')
    )
    category = forms.ChoiceField(label="Select a Category", choices=category_options, required=True)
    full_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.IntegerField)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 10, 'rows': 10}))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        
        return email
```

I'm not getting the phone field right. I need to add validation for phone numbers and couldn't figure out the right way to use widget for IntegerField.

I need to find the accurate way of adding a phone field.

I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError at /contact/
'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'
```

I get following results when I use

```
phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
```

[image]

My html generated from the python code for different fields is following:

```
<p> 
<label for="id_email">Email:</label>
<input id="id_email" name="email" type="email">
</p>

<p> 
<label for="id_phone">Phone:</label>
<input id="id_phone" name="phone" type="number">
</p>
```

Both my fields above are generated with python code but email field is applying template css properly. But "Phone" field is not rendering css.

Please advise.

Comment: don't know why you want `type="number"` for phone field.

Comment: Just use CharField and do all the validations inside `def clean_phone(self):` method.

Comment: Avinash I did that but I thought there could be some built in way to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign **the form field [forms.IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield)** to **"widget"** which is wrong:

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # ...                               # Wrong
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.IntegerField)
    # ...
```

So, instead, you need to assign **the widget [forms.NumberInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput)** to **"widget"** which is correct:

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # ...                               # Correct
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 6):

[`forms.IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) is not a widget but a field type on form.

What you need is a [`forms.NumberInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput)

```
phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
```

Comment: By your recommendation see above what I am getting. It is not getting my css instead its giving me a field that is not inheriting css at all. I've pasted the result as snapshot in original question above.

Comment: Can you also paste the HTML for the `phone` field and other fields as well? And, also how are you rendering this form in the view?

Comment: <p> 
<label for="id_email">Email:</label>
<input id="id_email" name="email" type="email">
</p>

<p> 
<label for="id_phone">Phone:</label>
<input id="id_phone" name="phone" type="number">
</p>

Comment: Please update this in question so it is available for everyone. And, please also include the css for both the inputs `email` and `phone` fields.

Comment: Please add the css as well. Because now your form is rendering and just the css for two fields is different. It could very well be that the css for `input[type=number]` is not set as it has been for other type of fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
      attrs={
          'type' : 'number',
          'class' : 'your_class'
      }))
```